# Amend 'text' of element by class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm stuck on something that I think should be dead simple (show's what I know!).

In HTML I've got:

```
<a class="removeQuantity"> - </a> 
<span class="quantity"> 1 </span>
<a onclick="addQuantity('2')"> + </a>
```

and in my script I've got the function:

```
function addQuantity(iQuant) {
    iQuant = parseInt(iQuant);
    $(this).prevAll('.quantity').text(iQuant.toString());
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is change the value contained the  with the class of quantity from 1 to the value passed into the function (2) but nothing seems to be working.

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks,
C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you assign an event handler using an `on*` attribute it does not set the scope to the current element, therefore `this` refers to the window, not the element which raised the event. To fix this you can pass the element reference directly to the function, like this:

```
<a onclick="addQuantity(2, this)"> + </a>
```

```js
function addQuantity(iQuant, el) {
    $(el).prevAll('.quantity').text(iQuant);
}
```

Note that in the above example I passed an integer directly to the function to avoid having to cast its type.

As a better alternative you could attach your event handlers using unobtrusive JS. Given you tagged the question with jQuery, here's how to do that:

```
<a class="quantity-amend" data-quantity="2"> + </a>
```

```js
$('.quantity-amend').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prevAll('.quantity').text($(this).data('quantity'));
});
```

> I can't use unobtrusive (I think!) as the the section of the page that I'm in gets reloaded when a quantity change is confirmed.

In this case you can use a delegated event handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '.quantity-amend', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prevAll('.quantity').text($(this).data('quantity'));
});
```

Comment: you are missing `e` in your code I corrected that and you reverted. I would prefer `.on` over `.click` because the former can use less memory and work for dynamically added elements.

Comment: @SusheelSingh thank you. Also note that the method signature of `on()` that you edited won't work for dynamic elements at all; for that you need to use `$('parent').on('event', 'child', fn)`;

Comment: yeah you are right I forgot the point. But I prefer using on everywhere for everthing. Its seems more generic to use and more readable:)

Comment: Should not the last snippet's `iQuant` be `$this.data("quantity")`?

Comment: @donkey you're correct! need more coffee this morning :)

Comment: `$(this).data("quantity")` by the way @donkey

Comment: You clever clever people worked a treat. I can't use unobtrusive (I think!) as the the section of the page that I'm in gets reloaded when a quantity change is confirmed. When the section is reloaded in with the confirmed values the HTML isn't being chained up the scripts (at least that's what I think is happening). Thanks for all your time :)

Comment: @SxChoc glad to help. Also note that you can still use an unobtrusive event handler in that case - I updated the answer for you with an example

Comment: Sharp eye @SusheelSingh!